Scapy AH Tunnel Mode
When AH is generated with Scapy   Security Association, Wireshark does not show the protocol type as AH and only displays the inner IP protocol in the packet listing.
from scapy.all import *
from scapy.layers.ipsec import *
from scapy.layers.ipsec import SecurityAssociation, AH

p = IP(src='192.168.100.6', dst='192.168.100.4')
p /= TCP(sport=45012, dport=80)
p /= Raw('testdata')
p = IP(raw(p))
p

sa = SecurityAssociation(AH, spi=0x222,
                         auth_algo='SHA2-256-128', auth_key=b'secret key',
                         tunnel_header=IP(src='11.11.11.11', dst='22.22.22.22'))
e = sa.encrypt(p)
response = sr1(e, iface="enp0s3", timeout=2)

Wireshark Capture
Is there any way to see AH mode correctly as well as the outer IP packet in AH. ESP seems to be OK in this regard.
